# compress or not png on web-server?

Tags: nginx, webserver, png, http-compression

Should I put the responce-header " Content-Encoding: gzip" for png-files, if client give me request-header "Accept-Encoding: gzip" with request?
As far as I know, and gzip and png both use algorithm Deflate. Whether a material difference with compress png or not?
Would not it be worse if I include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't do it. You are wasting CPU for nothing.